# Why am I getting this error TypeError: string indices must be integers?

Tags: python

```
def parse(self, response):
        result = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        for r in result:
            name = r["targetCeList"]
            print(name)
```

I don't understand why I get this error? I would be grateful if someone would correct my code and explain it to me

Comment: Show the JSON representation of the Response object in the question

Comment: Seems `r` is a string. strings do not have keys, only dicts do. So you can not do `"foo"["targetCeList"]`. You probably meant either `result["targetCeList"]` or `result[r]["targetCeList"]`, or use `result.values()`

Comment: cause your variable `r` is not a dictionary, it's a string, so you can't use `name = r["targetCeList"]`, try to print `r`